# Setting the UpdateCheck.Never mode by default in Visual Studio 2010 DBML designer (MS SQL/ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In my web application I do a lot of updates. And therefore the only acceptable UpdateCheck mode for all columns except for the primary key one is "NEVER".

But unfortunately the DBML designer automatically sets the "ALWAYS" mode. So I have to go through dozens of columns to change it manually, and when I have to update the DBML file... It goes back to "ALWAYS" again.

So is there a way to automatically set the mode you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution!

You can select several columns in the designer with the Shift key. And then do one mouse click.

I love Visual Studio :)

Comment: No shorter way still? Like some setting

Answer (score 0):

There IS a solution to make this default.

Just add a column with both name and type set to Timestamp to the desired table and then drop it to the DBML designer!

Visual Studio (at least VS 2010) will automatically set all other columns' Update Check to Never except the Timestamp column.

Credits to Simon_Weaver's answer here: [How much overhead does 'Update Check' have for LINQ UPDATES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330053/how-much-overhead-does-update-check-have-for-linq-updates)