# linq to sql , how to disable ChangeConflictException

Tags: linq-to-sql

i am using .net 4.0 ,
i hava a table agent , the agent has a field "accessed_date" which gets updated every 2 seconds , when he is logged in.

i have a service operation "UpdateAgent" , and as the name suggest it updates the agent , i dont want this operation to throw ChangeConflictException , if only the field "accessed_date" is updated , since i know , thats its normal that it will get updated , how i disable ChangeConflictException to get fired on submitchanges .

thanks
Jamal.

Answer (score 2):

You are implicitly using "Optimistic Concurrency". By default the UpdateCheck attribute is set to Always. Set the UpdateCheck to None for the accessed_date column.

Here's how (haven't tried, hope this works - if not, google for UpdateCheck.Never and check if one of the offered solutions works for you):
[Setting the UpdateCheck.Never mode by default in Visual Studio 2010 DBML designer (MS SQL/ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307243/setting-the-updatecheck-never-mode-by-default-in-visual-studio-2010-dbml-designer)

Comment: what if i want to disable Optimistic Concurrency for the whole table.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct way. If you really need to, you can either use an ordinary ExecuteCommand (meaning you write SQL strings again) or use Attach() - see articles http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/06/01/linq-to-sql-tips-7-minimal-update-when-you-don-t-want-optimistic-concurrency-check.aspx and http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/18/how-to-update-data-with-linq-to-sql/ for further details.

Comment: the method you defined will not work for me , beccause i have a timestamp column on this table . so updateecheck is set to false for each column except the time stamp column.IS THERE ANY OTHER SOLUTION NOW ?

Comment: How about removing the timestamp column from the dbml?
And adding this attribute doesn't help either?
[Column(Storage=“Timestamp”, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string Timestamp ....