# Confused with MS SQL Server LOCK would help in INSERT Scenario.(Concurrency)

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, sql-server-2008

**Business Scenario:** This is a ticketing system, and we got so many user using the application. When a ticket(stored in 1st table in below) comes in to the application, any user can hit the ownership button and take ownershipf of it.
Only one user can take ownership for one ticket. If two user tries to hit the ownership button, first one wins and second gets another incident or message that no incident exists to take ownership.
Here i am facing a concurrency issue now. I already have a lock implementation using another table(2nd table in below).

**I have two tables;**

Table(Columns)

1. Ticket(TicketID-PK, OwnerUserID-FK)
2. TicketOwnerShipLock(TicketID-PK, OwnerUserID-FK, LockDate)Note: Here TicketID is set as Primary Key.

**Current lock implementation:** whenever user one tries to own ticket puts an entry to 2nd table with TicketID, UserID and current date,then goes to update the OwnerUserID in 1st table.
Before insert the above said lock entry, Procedure checks for any other user already created any lock for the same incident.
If already there is lock, lock wont be opened for the user. Else lock entry wont be entered and the user cannot update the ticket onwership.
**More Info:** There are so many tickets getting opened in 1st table, whenever user tries to take ownership, we should find the next available ticket to take ownership. So need to find ticket and to do some calculation and set a status for that ticket, there one more column in 1st table StatusID. Status will be assigned as Assigned.

**Problem:** Somehow two user's got the ownership for same ticket at excatly same time, i have even checked the millisecond but that too same.
1. I would like to know if any MS SQL Server LOCK would help in this scenario. 
2. Or do i need to block table while insert.(This 2nd rable will not have much data approx. less than 15 rows)

**Lock Creation Procedure Below:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TakeOwnerShipGetLock] 
    @TicketId [uniqueidentifier],
    @OwnerId [uniqueidentifier]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION TakeOwnership
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @Lock BIT
        SET @Lock = 0

        DECLARE @LockDate DATETIME

        SELECT  @LockDate = LockDate
        FROM    dbo.TakeOwnershipLock
        WHERE   TicketId = @TicketId

        IF @LockDate IS NULL
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                FROM   dbo.TakeOwnershipLock as takeOwnership WITH (UPDLOCK)
                                INNER JOIN dbo.Ticket as Ticket WITH (NOLOCK)
                                ON Ticket.TicketID = takeOwnership.TicketId
                                WHERE  takeOwnership.TicketId = @TicketId
                                AND Ticket.OwnerID is NULL )
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO dbo.TakeOwnershipLock
                        ( TicketId
                        ,OwnerId
                        ,LockDate
                        )
                VALUES  ( @TicketId
                        ,@OwnerId
                        ,GETDATE()
                        )

                IF ( @@ROWCOUNT > 0 )
                    SET @Lock = 1
            END

        SELECT  @Lock

        COMMIT TRANSACTION TakeOwnership
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
        IF XACT_STATE() = 1
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION TakeOwnership
                SET @Lock = 1
                SELECT  @Lock
            END  

        -- Test whether the transaction is active and valid.   
        IF XACT_STATE() = -1
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TakeOwnership
                SET @Lock = 0
                SELECT  @Lock
            END     
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate following C# synchronization logic to Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586760/translate-following-c-sharp-synchronization-logic-to-stored-procedure)

Comment: You don't need any explicit locks. If you perform a simple `update tickets set owner = ... where owner is null` that will properly handle it and no two users will claim the same ticket.

Comment: Yes.... I don't understand the purpose of the second table - just update the first one with an appropriate where clause to reserve the ticket

Comment: We faced a concurrency issue here in Tickets table, so only we added another table to hold a lock for a user.

Comment: Then you will have that concurrency issue in the second table instead.

Comment: More Info: There are so many tickets getting opened in 1st table, whenever user tries to take ownership, we should find the next available ticket to take ownership. So need to find ticket and to do some calculation and set a status for that ticket, there one more column in 1st table StatusID. Status will be assigned as Assigned.

Comment: That does not change anything. Your query would still be `update top (1) tickets set owner = ... where owner is null`, or `update top (1) tickets set owner = ... where status <> 'Assigned'`, which is probably the same thing in your business logic.